# OutOfMemoryError when I request a volley http request periodic

Tags: java, android, httprequest, android-volley

in my app I check every 30 seconds the state from a light switch. I request the state over http with volley.

I get every 10 - 15 times the request run this message in my logcat:

> Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 38321(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 30(388KB) LOS objects, 36% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 5.197ms total 47.892ms

After I get this message several times my app crash with this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: de.resper.autoheim, PID: 4522 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again

This is the code in the main activity:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Check Light");
            wzControl.checkLight();
            if (wzControl.lightStatus) {
                rlWz.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.border_light));
            } else {
                rlWz.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
        }
    }, 1);
```

the checkLight method:

```
public void checkLight(){
    helper.sendUrl("http://mediaserver:8083/fhem?cmd=set%20WZ.Licht1%20statusRequest");
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.GET, "http://mediaserver:8083/fhem?cmd=jsonlist2%20WZ.Licht1&XHR=1", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String statValue = response.getJSONArray("Results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("Readings").getJSONObject("state").getString("Value");
                switch (statValue){
                    case "off":
                        lightStatus = false;
                        break;
                    case "on":
                        lightStatus = true;
                        break;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Could it be that the request sometimes get no response and than it try and try and so on?